# Apache: Cannot make exception for SSLVerifyClient whith server-level restriction

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, mod-ssl

I cannot make an exception for SSLVerifyCLient when it is at server level:

```
SSLVerifyClient require
SSLVerifyDepth 2
RequestHeader set SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY ""
<Location />
<If "-R '10.128.119.45/32'">
  SSLVerifyClient none
</If>
  SSLOptions +StdEnvVars ExportCertData OptRenegotiate
  RequestHeader set SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN "%{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN}s"
  RequestHeader set SSL_CLIENT_I_DN_CN "%{SSL_CLIENT_I_DN_CN}s"
  RequestHeader set SSL_CLIENT_CERT "%{SSL_CLIENT_CERT}s"
  RequestHeader set SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY "%{SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY}s"
  Require expr %{SSL_CLIENT_I_DN_CN} ==  'Example Users Authentication' && ( %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN}  ==  "user1" ||  %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN}  ==  "user55"  ||  %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN}  ==  "user2" ||  %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN}  ==  "user21575"  ||  %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN}  ==  "user3" || %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN}  ==  "user4")
</Location>
```

The exception is ignored at all:

> curl: (35) NSS: client certificate not found (nickname not specified)

I'd want to keep the "SSLVerifyClient require" at server level otherwise it produces some message as follows:

> AH02261: Re-negotiation handshake failed

I've tried with:

```
<If "-R '10.128.119.45/32'">
      SSLVerifyClient none
    </If>
```

outside of Location with no luck...

Am I missing something?

Comment: With TLSv1.3 browsers do not allow renegotiation by default, check if this is the case. I would also specify the expressions one by one instead of that huge expression.

Comment: AFAIK, there is not possible with TLSv1.3 clients to set SSLVerifyClient into Location or Directory  without failures , is it?